# How to collapse white space from a repositioned, floated div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make side notes for site, but if I use `absolute` positioning, when two citations are too close to each other, they will overlap. Using `relative` positioning, pushing the side note into the sidebar area of the page leaves white space behind, forcing the paragraph's text to wrap around the white space; is there a way to collapse that white space using JavaScript?

Or is there a different/better way to get the same effect using JavaScript?

It is crucial that the side notes are alongside the citation `--` not hidden and shown with JavaScript individually or simply listed separately like footnotes would be. And simply avoiding having citations that are too close is not an option.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orv2army/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main_column" class="grid_3 alpha omega">
    <p class="bodycopy">Donec ultricies massa vel dui lobortis, et ornare augue volutpat. Proin aliquam nec orci ut consequat. Donec sapien libero, tincidunt quis arcu vitae, hendrerit commodo neque.<sup>1</sup><small><strong>1</strong> Side note test. In imperdiet nibh turpis,
    eu scelerisque nisi sagittis eu. Fusce lectus tellus, pretium in venenatis eget, faucibus ac 
    eros.</small> In imperdiet nibh turpis, eu scelerisque nisi sagittis eu. Fusce lectus tellus, pretium in venenatis eget, faucibus ac eros.<sup>2</sup><small><strong>2</strong> Side note 
    test. In imperdiet nibh turpis, eu scelerisque nisi sagittis eu. Fusce lectus tellus, pretium 
    in venenatis eget, faucibus ac eros.</small> Phasellus nec efficitur magna.…</p>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
small {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: BrandonGrotesque, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    top: auto;
    margin-top: -28px;
    margin-left: 640px;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are tough. For example - what will you do if you have two citations that occur on the same line?

There might be a javascript solution to calculate the position of things and move them to an appropriate spot. I know that it's possible but I'm not the right guy to clearly write or explain it.

I think you can reduce the cases where you might have to compromise with smaller text and line-height:

```
small {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:110%
}
```

That would make them overlap less often, but to really do this right you need to figure out what you will do when two citations are on the same line. Aside from some kind of css hover/hide effect I think the only way is with some non-trivial javascript figuring out where to put things.

Comment: If they're on the same line, the second one would get bumped down. The requirements are really set by the fact that it's for academic writing.

I've made some headway on a JavaScript solution for doing this (basically a loop looking at each pair of notes, determining if they overlap and if so, pushing the second one down) -- but it needs a bit more work still.

But lowering the line height was a helpful suggestion! (I'm too much of a noob here to upvote anything, sorry.)

Comment: If you feel like someone's answer was helpful to you it's always a good idea to upvote. I'm not just saying that to get an upvote - it's a big part of what makes the site work. Accepting answers is also important, but you should only do that for answers that actually resolve your problem. Glad I was able to at least partially help - I think you're on the right track.

Comment: I would, but you need 15 reputation to update, and I only have 1!

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that rule, I haven't been on here in a while.

Comment: Heeey, I just got fifteen somehow. :)